# Why do I get an "unexpected token" error in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I'm a relative neophyte to Doxygen, but I thought I understood how to write a comment. I have a few stragglers now, complaining of "warning: unexpected token in comment block while parsing the argument of command param" on the following comment, complaining about the @brief line.

```
/**
  * @brief  Converts ADC reading to battery voltage
  * @param  adcVal raw ADC reading
  * @retval Battery voltage as float
  * @note   Assumes 12 bit ADC and 3.3 volt VCC
  * @note   Broken out for testability
  */
```

Can anybody tell me what might be the unexpected token? I've even resorted to retyping the comment block thinking I had an invisible character in there. (It's happened before...).

I didn't find anything in the Doxygen documentation that mentioned error messages.

And of course I assume I'm being particularly dense and stupid today...

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. Which language is the code written in that you try to document. What is the used filename? Any settings in the doxygen configuration file different from the standard settings? Please expand the example to a file in which shows your problem (my quick test didn't reveal any problem).

Comment: Doxygen is version 1.8.13. Language is C. The file names vary from one file to another, but the error remains the same. The only settings of which I'm aware of changing were the source directories.
I am apparently unable to provide a simple example of a file that produces the error message.

Comment: Neither with version 1.8.13 nor 1.8.14 I see a problem. Can you publish one of the files or are they to large? Otherwise take one file place it in a separate directory (outside your normal tree) place a Doxyfile with it and see if the problem still appears, if so try to prune the file (e.g. removing the body of the file) till you get a small enough file, if is not shown with one file not copy the complete tree and start pruning it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Lazy sot that I am, I kept an empty Doxygen comment block around that I could just copy and paste when I added a new function:

```
/**
    *   @brief
    *   @param
    *   @param
    *   @param
    *   @retval
    *   @note
    */
```

Well (empirically, anyway) it turns out that if you have a *real* comment block after that, say:

```
/**
  * @brief this is a dummy function
  * @param x is the input argument
  */
```

Doxygen gets confused. John gets confused.

So, mea culpa, but I found the problem.

Comment: Good that the problem is solved. Problem of course is also that the reported line number is a bit off. Maybe a good idea is to have the dummy comment start with `/*` instead of `/**` or have the comment block at the end of the file.

Comment: It's my understanding (I could very well be wrong - just ask my wife) that the "/**" tag is necessary for Doxygen to pick up the comment, and that "/*" doesn't. Thus the doubled asterisk.
I could use "/*!", but I still don't think that would help Doxygen figure out what to do. 
I checked, and this time I'm not wrong...

Comment: doxygen has different possibilities to signal comment that is to be picked up by doxygen. Doxygen requires `/**` or `/*!` or `///` or `//!` (see documentation) the "default" comments `/*` and `//` are seen by doxygen as non documentation cmments.